# How to change button color in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 `buttons` and they are all `blue`.  When you click on one of those button, the button that is clicked should change to `red`.  But the other four buttons should remain in `blue`.  In addition, if you click the button two or more times, it should not change the color back to `blue`.  For example, If I click on `button one` it will change to `red`, if i click `button one` again, it should be `red` and not `blue`, the color only change if you click another button.  It is like `radio` buttons but I need an `<a>` tag and I can't use `radio buttons`

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-center">
<a onclick="changeColor()" href="applications-new.php?program_id=1" id="one" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp I</a>
<a onclick="changeColor()" href="applications-new.php?program_id=2" id="two" name="program-2" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp II</a>
<a onclick="changeColor()" href="applications-new.php?program_id=3" id="three" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp III</a>
<a onclick="changeColor()" href="applications-new.php?program_id=4" id="four" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">LSPP I</a>
<a onclick="changeColor()" href="applications-new.php?program_id=5" id="five" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">LSAT</a>
```

**JS**

```
function changeColor(){

    if(document.getElementById('one').clicked === true)
     {
       document.getElementById('one').style.background = "red";
     }else {
       document.getElementById('one').style.background = "#012D6B";
     }

     if(document.getElementById('two').clicked === true)
     {
       document.getElementById('two').style.background = "red";
     }else {
       document.getElementById('two').style.background = "#012D6B";
     }

     if(document.getElementById('three').clicked === true)
     {
       document.getElementById('three').style.background = "red";
     }else {
       document.getElementById('three').style.background = "#012D6B";
     }

     if(document.getElementById('four').clicked === true)
     {
       document.getElementById('four').style.background = "red";
     }else {
       document.getElementById('four').style.background = "#012D6B";
     }

     if(document.getElementById('five').clicked === true)
     {
       document.getElementById('five').style.background = "red";
     }else {
       document.getElementById('five').style.background = "#012D6B";
     }
}
```

My `js` doesn't work.  Also, I believe that there is a better way to do this without 5 `if` and 5 `else` statement

PS: this is my `css` just in case:

```
.bkgrnd-dkblue {
background-color: #012D6B;
color: #FFF;
}

 .btn-width{
  width:130px;

}

 .change-btn-color:hover {

   background-color: #9DC9BA;
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: What is wrong with my question -_-?

Comment: Why can't you use radio buttons? Also If you are using `<a>` tags with a `href` why do the buttons need to update? once you click them you will be directed to another page and they will just be reset.

Comment: @AlfieB I am using `$_GET` so I will use the `?program_id=#` on other pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class that makes the background red, and then toggle the class on the element clicked. When you click the button the first time, it will add the class, and the background will change. When you click it again, it will remove the class and turn the background-color "normal" again.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="text-center">
<a onclick="changeColor(this)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=1" id="one" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp I</a>
<a onclick="changeColor(this)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=2" id="two" name="program-2" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp II</a>
<a onclick="changeColor(this)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=3" id="three" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp III</a>
<a onclick="changeColor(this)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=4" id="four" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">LSPP I</a>
<a onclick="changeColor(this)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=5" id="five" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">LSAT</a>
```

**JS:**

```
function changeColor(el){
    jQuery(el).toggleClass('red');
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.red {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Try `jQuery(this)` and not `jQuery(el)` :-)

Comment: i think that bootstrap is not letting me do something because not even the answer that include a working version is not working in my code

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
 $(".btn").removeClass("btn-red"); //fallback 
  $(this).addClass("btn-red"); // add color 
});
```

```css
.btn {
 display:inline-block;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:6px 12px;
    color:#fff;
}
.btn-blue {
 background-color:blue;
}
.btn-red {
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">button</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var specialColor='red';
var defaultColor='#012D6B';

$(".text-center a").bind("click",function(){
    $(this).css("background-color",specialColor);
  var currentId=$(this).attr('id');
  $(".text-center a[id!="+currentId+"]").css("background-color",defaultColor);
});
```

I think this will help you, but you'll have to include jquery in file/project.
https://jsfiddle.net/bqL7sqde/

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not using jQuery I assume that you want to use pure Javascript instead. What you can do is call changeColor(this) to pass in the clicked element then change the color of the element to red. Afterwards retrieve the sibling elements and change the other items except the clicked item to blue. Here's a JSFiddle with an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/603obh3v/1/

```
function changeColor(element){
  element.style.color = "red";
  var siblings = element.parentElement.children;

  for(var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
    if(siblings[i] !== element) {
        siblings[i].style.color = "blue";
    }
  }
}

<div class="text-center">
  <a onclick="changeColor(this)" href="#" id="one" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp I</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this)" href="#" id="two" name="program-2" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp II</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this)" href="#" id="three" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp III</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this)" href="#" id="four" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">LSPP I</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this)" href="#" id="five" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">LSAT</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS solution,

```js
function changeColor(el, event) {


  event.preventDefault(); //remove this line

  function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
  }

  var allAnchor = document.getElementsByTagName('a')

  var temp = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < allAnchor.length; i++) {
    if (hasClass(allAnchor[i], 'btn')) {
      temp = allAnchor[i];
      temp.style.backgroundColor = "#012D6B";
    }
  };

  el.style.backgroundColor = "#FF9800";


}
```

```css
.bkgrnd-dkblue {
  background-color: #012D6B;
  color: #FFF;
}
.btn-width {
  width: 130px;
}
.change-btn-color:hover {
  background-color: #9DC9BA !important;
}
/*custom style below*/

a {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #9E9E9E;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background ease-in .2s;
}
div.text-center {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=1" id="one" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp I</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=2" id="two" name="program-2" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp II</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=3" id="three" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp III</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=4" id="four" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">LSPP I</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=5" id="five" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">LSAT</a>
```

javascript alternative method

```js
function changeColor(el, event) {

  event.preventDefault(); //remove this line

  var allAnchor = document.querySelectorAll('a.btn');
  for (var i = 0; i < allAnchor.length; i++)
    allAnchor[i].className = allAnchor[i].className.replace(/active/g, '');

  el.className += ' active';

}
```

```css
.bkgrnd-dkblue {
  background-color: #012D6B;
  color: #FFF;
}
.btn-width {
  width: 130px;
}
.change-btn-color:hover {
  background-color: #9DC9BA;
}
/*custom style below*/

a {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #9E9E9E;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background ease-in .2s;
}
div.text-center {
  display: block
}
a.active,
a.active:hover {
  background: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=1" id="one" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp I</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=2" id="two" name="program-2" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp II</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=3" id="three" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp III</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=4" id="four" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">LSPP I</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=5" id="five" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">LSAT</a>

</div>
```

with Jquery

```js
$('a.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //remove this line
  $('a.btn').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

})
```

```css
.bkgrnd-dkblue {
  background-color: #012D6B;
  color: #FFF;
}
.btn-width {
  width: 130px;
}
.change-btn-color:hover {
  background-color: #9DC9BA;
}
/*custom style below*/

a {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #9E9E9E;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background ease-in .2s;
}
div.text-center {
  display: block
}
a.active,
a.active:hover {
  background: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center">
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=1" id="one" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp I</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=2" id="two" name="program-2" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp II</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=3" id="three" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">Boot Camp III</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=4" id="four" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">LSPP I</a>
  <a onclick="changeColor(this,event)" href="applications-new.php?program_id=5" id="five" name="program-1" class="btn btn-md bkgrnd-dkblue btn-width change-btn-color">LSAT</a>
```

Hope this helps..:)